# Android app pulling Json from web, has large data and cache storage?

Tags: android, json, android-sqlite

I developed an app pulling json from web and store some texts into sqlite database. After using it sometime, i noticed it has 30 MB of data storage and 40Mb of cache. I dont understand why the data is so large given that its only few lines of text (for testing).

I wonder if there is any way to manage this? please let me know

Answer (score 0):

For the best result could you post the code and I could have assumption that probably you didn't delete the whole DB when you exit the app that's why it keeps increasing and could cause your app very slow.

Comment: I actually dont want to delete the database. I just update it. Any reasons that you suggest to delete the database after exitting

Comment: I am worried that when you does update, you didn't check whether there is an duplicate data or not and you just insert it again so there is multiple data on your DB that could cause you memory leak. for me, I used greendao to maintain my DB its much more easy to setup and also easy to do. and less memory consume. here the link https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO